# VIM "d%" (delete to matching brace/paren) behavior change

Tags: vim, editor

I recently did a new install of VIM 8.2.2825 on Windows.  The behavior of `<operator>%`, such as `d%` or `c%` appears to have changed, compared to how I have used those commands for many years.  These operations are now "exclusive", meaning they do not include the final paren or brace in the text that you want to delete or change.

The documentation still claims that the `<op>%` operation is inclusive.  (see the beginning of section 9 (various motions) in `:help motion.txt`).  But that's not happening.  If the cursor is on the left paren and I type `d%`, it now deletes everything before the right paren, but not the right paren.  It should include deleting the right paren.

I searched quite a while looking for anything related to the inclusivity / exclusivity of the `d%` operation, with no luck.  Apologies if I missed something.

I'm wondering if this really is a change in VIM behavior (in which case the documentation seems to be wrong), or if perhaps there is some `.vimrc` setting that I now need, that wasn't needed before.
TIA.

Comment: This would be a perfect fit for [Vim's issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues). Also, did you mean `d%` instead of `%d`?

Comment: Oops, yes, it's `d%`.  Correction made, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using `:h matchit` standard plugin that re-maps `%`. In fact, it does not necessarily make the motion exclusive, it just uses Visual mode that depends on your `:h 'selection'` setting.

Just don't load it if you don't like it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, although that wasn't the problem.  I think my _vimrc file (which worked fine with vim 7.x) had some outdated stuff in it, and that may have been the problem.  So I started from scratch, reinstalled 8.2, and then more carefully merged my _vimrc changes, and that seems to have fixed this immediate problem of the `d%` behavior change.   I am still working through a few other behavior changes.